# Openshift4 installation on Virtualbox

Tags: openshift, virtualbox

Who has installed Openshift4 on Virtualbox VMs? How to bypass BMC limitations (BMC is required in install-config.yaml)?

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/installing/installing_bare_metal_ipi/ipi-install-installation-workflow.html#configuring-the-install-config-file_ipi-install-configuration-files

Answer (score 1):

The [prerequisites](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/installing/installing_bare_metal_ipi/ipi-install-prerequisites.html) for an OCP 4.6 IPI (Installer Provisioned Infrastructure) install requires BMC access to each node.

With this setup a UPI (User Provisioned Infrastucture) deployment would be a better fit. You would need to set up the VMs and DNS entries before starting the deployment, as described in https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/installing/installing_bare_metal/installing-bare-metal.html#installation-requirements-user-infra_installing-bare-metal.